# Objective-C split string, separator being the last characters of

Tags: objective-c

I have this piece of code here:

```
NSArray *elements = [[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"];
```

but this creates multiple objects because my string looks like this Thiss\is\a\test and I want to split my string or just get the last part of the string after the last `\\` characters. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *elements = [[[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"] lastObject];
```

Should work for you.

Comment: This works, thanks, I even changed my NSArray to NSString

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString* wholeString = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
NSArray* components = [wholeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"];
NSString* lastPart = [components lastObject];
NSString* allExceptLast = [wholeString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:lastPart withString:@""];
allExceptLast = [allExceptLast stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
```